Python code execution too slow due to bottleneck - seeking performance optimization
I'm currently facing a performance issue with my Python code, specifically with the execution speed. I've identified a bottleneck in my code, and I'm seeking advice on how to optimize it for better performance.
Here's a simplified version of the code:
import numpy as np

def merge_arrays(arr: list, new: list) -> list:
  if len(arr) != len(new):
    raise ValueError(f'Length of <inds> is {len(arr)} but length of <new> is {len(new)}')
  else:
    return transform_array(zip(arr, new), [])

def transform_array(arr: list, r: list):
  for x in arr:
    if isinstance(x, (list, tuple, np.ndarray)):
        transform_array(x, r)
    else:
        r.append(x)
  return r

COUNT = 100000

pips = [(np.arange(5), np.arange(5)) for _ in range(COUNT)]
b = [np.arange(50, 65) for _ in range(COUNT)]
ang = [np.arange(50, 55) for _ in range(COUNT)]
dist = [np.arange(50, 55) for _ in range(COUNT)]

result = [merge_arrays(y, [np.append(b[i][1:], [dist[i][p], ang[i][p]]) for p, i in enumerate(x)]) for x, y in pips]

The issue arises when dealing with large datasets, particularly when the input lists contain a significant number of elements. This leads to slow execution times, which is undesirable for my application.
I've tried to optimize the code by using list comprehensions and avoiding unnecessary condition checks, but the performance is still not satisfactory.
I'm looking for suggestions on how to refactor or optimize this code to improve its performance, especially in the transform_array function where the bottleneck seems to be located.
Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Reducing the overhead of isinstance
One problem is that the code makes 9_500_000 calls to isinstance. This is far to much for an interpreted code. Not to mention type introspection is never fast. If we can make the assumption that some items have a well known type and do not need to be tested, then the code can be improved.
There is a solution for Numpy array since they are typed as opposed to CPython tuples and CPython lists. Note that storing (list, tuple, np.ndarray) in a variable make this 10% faster. Here is a faster code based on this:
T1 = (list, tuple)
T2 = (np.ndarray,)

def transform_array(arr: list, r: list):
  for x in arr:
    if isinstance(x, T1):
        transform_array(x, r)
    elif isinstance(x, T2):
        if x.dtype == object:
            # Generic case
            transform_array(x, r)
        else:
            # No need to check all items: 
            # Push back all the items of the array in the list
            r.extend(x.tolist())
    else:
        r.append(x)
  return r

Once this optimization is done, >95% of the time is spent in the result = ... list comprehension and not even in merge_arrays calls. 50% of this time is spent in np.append.

Reducing the overhead of Numpy calls
Numpy calls in the list comprehension are quite expensive. This is mainly because Numpy is not designed to do operations on very small array nor to extract many scalar items manually. On top of that np.append is designed to append arrays (and not lists) to arrays so it first converts the list to an array which is also quite expensive (not to mention it needs to check the types of all the items in it).
We can reduce the overhead by doing the operation manually.  Here is a faster implementation:
#import numba as nb
#@nb.njit(['(int32[:], int32[:], int32[:], int64)', '(int64[:], int64[:], int64[:], int64)'])
def build_item(b_i, dist_i, ang_i, p):
    out = np.empty(b_i.size+1, dtype=b_i.dtype)
    out[:-2] = b_i[1:]
    out[-2] = dist_i[p]
    out[-1] = ang_i[p]
    return out

# [...]

result = [merge_arrays(y, [build_item(b[i], dist[i], ang[i], p) for p, i in enumerate(x)]) for x, y in pips]

The line result = ... takes 1.66 seconds on my machine as opposed to 5.92 second for the initial code. It is thus 3.6 times faster.

Can you explain "Note that storing (list, tuple, np.ndarray) in a variable make this 10% faster" why?

I think the tuple needs to be recreated every time and this is a bit slower than creating a global variable. Moreover, for np.ndarray, the objects needs to be fetched in the np namespace. In the answer, this is the global variables T1 and T2.

Understood. Another question about the numba. If I get it correctly, it can be used only for functions with predefined types, array sizes and so on? And I can't use if for merge_arrays or transform_array functions in this case, right?

I removed the information about Numba except the two lines used to JIT compile in the code which are now commented. This is because the benefit was very small if any... I think this is because the allocation are the most expensive part of the function though one need to profile this. You can specify the signature so to pre-compile the function eagerly. If you do not, then the function is automatically lazily compiled at runtime when you call the function for the first time. This can introduce a significant overhead though (e.g. 0.05 sec to 1-2 seconds).

Note that the types need to be native ones (objects are not really supported in practice -- at least this is useless to try to compile functions using objects in Numba). Besides, I am not sure exceptions are supported since they are pure Python objects after all, so merge_arrays is certainly not jittable.
